# fsockopen in php not working on server

Tags: php, fsockopen

Here is my code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("74.63.172.37", 22, $errno, $errstr, 50);

if (!$fp) {

    echo "not connected";

} else {

    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: 74.63.172.37\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $val = "";
    if (!feof($fp)) {
        echo "<br/>".fgets($fp, 128);
    }

    if (feof($fp)) {
        echo "<br/>Not connected";
    } else {
      echo "<br/>Connected";
    }

    fclose($fp);

    die();
}
```

On local server it gives me an output:

```
trying to connect
SSH-2.0-1.82_sshlib GlobalSCAPE
Connected
```

Whereas on server it gives me an output:

```
trying to connect
Not connected
```

I have another sftp server, where I could connect from both server and locally.
What could be the issue?

Comment: please obfuscate or change your IP address to something like 111.111.111.111... It's SSH open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks ,, I found the solution. Destination Host has blocked my Server IP address.

Answer (score 2):

It is either not enabled by your ISP, or the ports are being blocked. I would suggest you contact the servicedesk.

Comment: forgot to mention. I have an another sftp server, where I could connect from both server and locally.

Comment: you could use curl? if its only the contents youre intetrsted in? so, you have 3 servers, 2 function, 1 doesn’t?

Comment: Cant change the code for connecting to sftp server. It is working fine for other servers.

Comment: Then it must be a  configuration issue. my answer stands then. contact the service desk of your isp to ask them to enable/unblock fsock.

Comment: Which isp. Ftp server or server from where Iam calling to ftp. I can connect to My FTP server locally so there is no issue on that. Where as my server (from where Iam connecting to ftp) can connect to several other ftps and working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Two options I can think of:

the destination server will only accept connections from a particular IP address, and your Web server isn't on it.

The version of Open SSL on your web server is not compatible, so the cypher used for connectivity can't be agreed. Or it's trying to fall back to protocol 1, but the destination sever is configured to only allow protocol 2 (the latest).

So - check if there is a firewall restriction on destination server, and check openssl is up to date and cyphers are all available on your web server.